# Is it possible to modify live call statusCallback value?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Is it possible to modify the statusCallback, statusCallbackEvent and statusCallbackMethod of the live call ?

I've used this article as a reference `https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/modify-live-calls` 
In the article, it said you can POST to update the live call but when I tried to update the statusCallback URL, it's not working. There is nothing trigger new statusCallback URL when the call end.

My use case is to

1. Tracking call status of inbound call
2. Tracking call status of outbound call from Web Client (which we use TwilioClient SDK to make a call to Twiml App)

I know that I can set the statusCallback URL in phone number page for inbound call and in Twiml App page for outbound call. But there are 2 problems with that.

1. There is no field to specify the statusCallbackEvent type I need.
2. my statusCallback URL is generated dynamically so I can't use hardcode the statusCallback URL. (that's why I'm trying to update the statusCallback URL) `(eg. ${BASE_URL}/voice/:conferenceKey/call/callback)`

I'm using NodeJS and here is the example code I used to update the statusCallback. I've also double check that call_sid is matched with live call sid.

```
return client.calls(call_sid)
         .update({
           statusCallback: `${process.env.API_HOST}/voice/${conferenceKey}/call/callback`,
           statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
           statusCallbackEvent: ['answered', 'completed'],
         });
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The only things you can update for a call that's in progress are the current URL (redirect the call to new TwiML) or the status (set to complete to end the call). You can't update the statusCallback URL during a call.

If your calls are going to a conference, then might [conference statusCallback events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent) help?

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! `conference statusCallback` is not helping in my usecase. I do a warm transfer from Web Dashboard A to Web Dashboard B. The moment I do a warm transfer, I updated the user status to `'pending'` (so I can show connecting/loading UI on Web) and updated to `'end'` on 'busy' call event (in case Web Dashboard B reject the call) but if I use conference statusCallback, I have no way to detect that the call was rejected. 'participant-leave' event is not triggered because participant didn't join the conference in the first place

Comment: Have you considered storing information about the call against it's `CallSid` that way, when you receive the incoming webhook to the single status callback URL you can decide what to do with the information based on that `CallSid`?

Comment: Your suggestion work out well :) I store related information I want against CallSid and use CallSid to fetch those on callback hook. It solves my problem. Thanks!